# ethers getBlockNumber doesn't return a new value on BSC testnet

Tags: ethers.js

I have the following code in a loop that gets the current block number:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
```

The problem is `blockNumber` doesn't seem to update. It remains the same number without ever increasing. It makes `provider.getLogs` hard to use. This behavior happens on BSC tesnet but not on Eth rinkeby. How can I get it unstuck?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a node problem, in the following example I'm using the GetBlock free node and it works fine :)

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const getBlock = async() => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://bsc.getblock.io/testnet/?api_key=INPUT_YOUR_API_KEY");
    const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
    console.log(blockNumber)
}

getBlock();
```

Comment: Your solution uses an API key, but this is for a frontend where people will see/steal it?

Comment: You can use dotenv :)

Comment: Couldn't someone get that value by inspecting the source files when visiting the frontend from a browser?

Comment: Nodejs is server-side code, so it is typically not publicly accessible :)

Comment: Sorry I should have specified in the question that this is for a website frontend, not a sever

Comment: Oh, I think you can use the public node which BSC Official provided. [BSC NODE LIST](https://docs.bscscan.com/misc-tools-and-utilities/public-rpc-nodes)

Comment: It can be worked, but it will be slower than the private node :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Simplest Possible way  
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://data-seed-prebsc-1- 
   s1.binance.org:8545/");


const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

The replication time for a block to be fully replicated across all nodes on the BlockChain net can be expected to be relatively fast, typically within a few seconds to a few minutes at most.
So the block number might not to be updated immediately.